# How to call performSegueWithIdentifier in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a prepareForSegue method and I am trying to call it from a button that I created by using the performSegueWithIdentifier method. The app is crashing when I load the simulator and it's not getting me a complete error message. Can someone please lead me in the right direction?

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKShareKit
import FBSDKLoginKit

class PageContentViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var logoImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var contentLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var backgroundImageView: UIImageView!


    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!

    @IBOutlet weak var facebookButton: UIButton!

    var index : Int = 0
    var logoFile: String = ""
    var content: String = ""
    var backgroundFile: String = ""

    let facebookReadPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        pageControl.currentPage = index

        facebookButton.hidden = (index == 3 ) ? false : true
        pageControl.hidden = (index == 3) ? true: false

        logoImageView.image = UIImage(named: logoFile)
        contentLabel.text = content
        backgroundImageView.image = UIImage(named: backgroundFile)
    }



    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

        if let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as? PaymentSubViewController
            where segue.identifier == "payment" {
                // Do something with `destinationController`
        }
    }


    @IBAction func test(sender: AnyObject) {

           self.performSegueWithIdentifier("payment", sender: self)

    }




    @IBAction func fbTouched(sender: AnyObject) {
        FBSDKLoginManager().logInWithReadPermissions(self.facebookReadPermissions, handler: { (result:FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                //According to Facebook:
                //Errors will rarely occur in the typical login flow because the login dialog
                //presented by Facebook via single sign on will guide the users to resolve any errors.

                // Process error
                FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
            } else if result.isCancelled {
                // Handle cancellations
                FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
            } else {
                let fbToken = result.token.tokenString

                Alamofire.request(Router.FacebookAuth(fbToken)).validate(statusCode: 200 ..< 300).responseJSON(completionHandler: { (request, response, JSON, error) in
                    if let json = JSON as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                        if let token = json["token"] as? String {
                            Router.OAuthToken = token
                            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showHomeFeed", sender: self)
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are force unwrapping the `destinationViewController` using `as!`, if that value is `nil` or not a `PaymentSubViewController`, the app will crash.

The better way to implement this is with an optional binding (`if let`) and a conditional downcast (`as?`):

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

    if let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as? PaymentSubViewController
        where segue.identifier == "payment" {
            // Do something with `destinationController`
    }
}
```

Of course, that'll stop the crash but won't answer the question of why `segue.destinationViewController` is `nil` or of another type.  Make sure that you segue is configured properly in interface builder and that the destination view controller actually has `segue.destinationViewController` for its **Class** value in the identity inspector tab.

Comment: Its still crashing when I try to run it

Comment: Can you post the error message you receive or even a screenshot of crash that includes the stack trace?

Comment: I can't post a picture because this is a new account, but the error is stop in the self.performSegueWithIdentifier("payment", sender: self) and says "Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1"

Comment: Its there now for you to see

Answer (score 0):

I had a map object on the storyboard and I did not add an outlet for the object which was creating an error message.